# monotonically increasing bijective mapping with the property that $\phi$ and $\phi^{(-1)}$ are both continuously differentiable

Tags: measure-theory

$[a,b]$and$[c,d]$compact real intervals. Let $\phi:[a,b]\to[c,d]$

monotonically increasing bijective mapping with the property that $\phi$ and $\phi^{(-1)}$ are both continuously differentiable

Now I want to show that $\int_{a}^{b}f(\phi(x))dx=\int_{c}^{d}f(x)\frac{1}{\phi'(\phi^{-1}(x))}dx$ applies to all continuous functions $f:[c,d]\to\mathbb{R}$

Can anyone explain to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just carry on the substitution

$$t:=\phi(x)\implies dt=\phi'(x)dx\implies dx=\frac{dt}{\phi'(x)}$$

But we now have to express $\;\phi'(x)\;$ as a function of the new variable $\;t\;$ , so we use the given data + the theorem about the derivative of the inverse function:

$$t=\phi(x)\implies x=\phi^{-1}(t)\implies\phi'(x)=\phi'\left(\phi^{-1}(t)\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the substitution $u=\phi(x)$, then $du=\phi'(x)dx$, so we get
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(\phi(x))dx=\int_{c}^{d}f(u)\frac{1}{\phi'(x)}du=\int_{c}^{d}f(u)\frac{1}{\phi'(\phi^{-1}(u))}du$$